# Generate the list [1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, ...]

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, restricted-source, restricted-complexity

In the spirit of [a question on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130547/getting-the-sequence-1-0-1-0-1-0-1-0-without-trig): given an integer `n`, return the integer in position `n` of the sequence [1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, ...]. Assume `n >= 0`.

Rules:

1. You may only use the operations -x, x+y, x-y, x*y, x/y, and x<sup>y</sup>, whatever their representations are in the language you choose.
2. Your function must be called `a`.
3. Your function must run in constant time for all `n`.

Example:

```
a=lambda n:((-1)**(n*n-n)//2)+(-1)**(n*n+n)//2))//2
```

Non-example (uses list subscripting operation and modulo operator):

```
a=lambda n:[1,0,-1,0][n%4]
```

Non-example (uses cos operation):

```
from math import *;a=lambda n:int(cos(n*pi/2))
```

Non-example (does not run in constant time and uses if operation):

```
a=lambda n:-a(n-2) if n>1 else 0 if n>0 else 1
```

**Clarifications:** Both integer and float division are allowed. Your solution may return either an integer or a float (or complex number, I suppose, since some answers already used it). If your solution returns a float: your solution should, if it were to theoretically be carried out to infinite precision, give the exact answer.

Comment: Is the allowed `x/y` any kind of division (including `div`) or always floating point division? — Certainly, "Your function must run in constant time for all `n`" is limited to some reasonable limit, no need to work for bigInts?

Comment: What about conditionals, Boolean negation, etc?

Comment: Your example uses ** and // but you didn't allow them. a) What does ** and // mean, and why can you use them?

Comment: @user unknown: Sorry I didn't make that clear. `x**y` is x to the yth power and `x//y` is integer division.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Conditionals, boolean negation, and such are not allowed. My real goal here was to translate that math problem I linked into a code golf problem.

Comment: Um. Conditionals, Boolean algebra, etc. are perfectly cromulent mathematical objects.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Of course they are, but the author of the other question on math.se asked for solutions that used only things you would find on a basic pocket calculator. I wanted to stay true to that restriction.

Comment: In that case you should have disallowed exponentiation and complex numbers. Too late now, but next time you might want to post your question on the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/423/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-iii) thread in meta to get a bit of feedback before people start answering.

Comment: How does the restriction on the name of the function work in languages where functions can't be named, or where `a` isn't a valid function name?

Comment: Also: It's impossible to solve this in constant time. Reading `n` takes time O(log n). VTC as unclear.

Comment: @user202729 This is incorrect.  You do not actually need to read the input, since the output is periodic (with period) you only need to read the last 2 bits.  Hypothetically if your input is provided as a bit stream you can do this in constant time.  However it does not look like any of the answers here actually do that.

Comment: @HatWizard in little endian. ... not a bad point.

Answer (score 5):

#### Ruby, 26 characters

```
a=->n{1-(k=n-n/4*4)+k/3*2}
```

Example:

```
> p (0..10).map{|n| a[n]}
[1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1]
```

Note: This solution assumes that integer division `/` is an allowed operation.

Comment: I know it's been 6 years (lol..), but it can be golfed by 1 byte by reusing `n` instead of using a new variable `k`: `a=->n{1-(n-=n/4*4)+n/3*2}`. [Try it online **25 bytes**](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvs/0VbXLq/aUFcjT9c2T99Ey0RTO0/fWMuo9n@BgoaBnp6hgaZebmJBdU1ejUJidF5s7X8A).

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 29 chars

```
a=lambda n:(1j**n+(-1j)**n)/2
```

Kind of cheating, but fun.

### Edit:

Now that we can return complex numbers, this is competitive and no longer cheating (with Howard's suggestion).

Comment: I think that operator `.real` is not supported by the rules. You may use `(j**n+(-j)**n)/2` instead.

Comment: Should be `1j**-n`.

Comment: `1j**-n` instead of `(-1j)**n` saves 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 36 chars

```
a(n){return(1-n+n/2*2)*(1-n+n/4*4);}
```

The same function used by Peter Taylor.

Comment: By using `a(n){return(n-n/2*2)*(2-n+n/4*4);}` you can shave off two characters.

Comment: @Superbest, this gives the series shifted by one position. Close, but not it.

Comment: According to http://codepad.org/sO0mFkhI output from your function is `0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, ...`. Output from mine is `1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1`. The original question gives the example output `1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, ...`.

Comment: @Superbest, you seem to start with `n=1`, I start with `n=0`. All examples (except the first, which gives a syntax error), give `a(0)=1`, like my answer. You can say your suggestion is valid, because it gives the same series starting from another position, but I'll stick with my version.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I'm not sure why I thought the first one was 1 not 0. Sorry.

Comment: C is best! thanks for algorithmic approach!

Comment: I know it's been almost six years (lol..), but you can golf it to `a(n){return 1-(n-=n/4*4)+n/3*2;}` by creating a port of Howard's answer. [Try it online **32 bytes**.](https://tio.run/##DclBCoMwEAXQvaf4CMKMMVjbdBU9TIhaZtGxBO1GPHvM5m1etJ8Ycw6kfKZlP5JisKR20t61jo32r/bpr/zfZMY3iBKfFbBuiUR3yPTwkHF4F43hMsAvlVmpbuYOdYdAwuyrK98)

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 36 chars

```
a=lambda n:(-1)**(n/2)*(1+(-1)**n)/2
```

Answer (score 2):

### J, 18 characters

```
a=:[:{.[:+._1^2%~]
```

Works, but is probably cheating by the rules set out above.

Calculates -1 to the power of the given integer divided by 2 which gives `0j1` for any odd number. The `{.` and the `+.` return the real part so that the odd numbers give 0.

Usage:

```
   a 1
0
   a 6
_1
```

Edit: After feeling a bit smug about this I've just looked properly at Keith's answers and realized I've done essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript (<strike>20</strike> 19 chars)

```
{.4/4*-.3/2*)\-}:a;
```

This is a port of [Howard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1490/howard)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/generate-the-list-1-0-1-0-1-0-1-0/5524#5524).

If, in addition to division, the remainder operation were permitted, this could be improved substantially (by <strike>6</strike> 5 chars):

```
{.2%(\4%(*}:b;
```

Mathematically that's

```
x => (x%2 - 1) (x%4 - 1)
```

I can't see any logic behind excluding remainder, since it's *defined* in terms of permitted operations.

Comment: I think you should spend a semicolon after your code. Otherwise it interferes with the input to your program.

Comment: @Howard, I see your point. I think it's arguable, because the spec's badly worded, but on balance I think the leave-it-off position is weaker.

Answer (score 1):

**Python, 34 chars**

Poor man's modulus... saves a whopping 2 chars over Keith Randall's solution.  Take that!  ;)

```
a=lambda n:(n-1-n/2*2)*(n-1-n/4*4)
```

edit: on reading others' solutions, this is the same as Peter Taylor's

Answer (score 0):

### bc: 28 chars

```
echo 'a=4;(1-a+a/2*2)*(1-a+a/4*4)' | bc
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 49 chars

```
a=lambda n:(lambda x:(x**3-3*x*x-x+3)/3)(n-n/4*4)
```

Note: In Python3 you'll have to replace n/4 with n//4 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**8086 Assembler** (14 bytes of machine code):

```
 ; ax holds the index into the sequence
 ; returns the sequence value in ax
 a: inc al
    shl al,6
    sar al,6
    cbw
    xor al,ah
    add al,ah
    cbw                     
    ret
```

Comment: But in machine code, it isn't named `a`. The name's only used by the assembler and by the linker, so you'd have to count the length of the assembly code or the object code (unless the OP clarifies that it's ok for the function to be named `0` instead, which would be the closest analogue to the name of a function in machine code).

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 12 bytes

```
i^Ans+i^-Ans
Ans/2
```

Store in `prgmA` and run with `5:prgmA`, with the input in place of `5`.

TI-Basic implicitly returns the last evaluated value.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
a=lambda n:(n/2*2-n+1)*1j**n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBDsIgEEbhfU/xJ24AMQruTLyFFxgtWkw7TNph0dNTli/fk12nwrE1es60vEcCPwxfo4sXPgfrwt85bie8poRv5Y/mwsgbFhJJI3oQtMrctazQtGnm3zDImllNnwz5zFLVWGubuXkEj@hxtwc)

Proof of validity for those who don't know Python:

The expression is `(n/2*2-n+1)*1j**n`. If you add parentheses, it becomes `((((n/2)*2)-n)+1)*(1j**n)`. `/` is integer division, since both `n` and `2` are integers in this case, `*` is multiplication, `-` is subtraction, `+` is addition and `**` is exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 21 bytes

```java
n->1-(n-=n/4*4)+n/3*2
```

Port of [*@Howard*'s Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5524/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BDoIwEETvfMWGU0sFRLkh/oFcOBoPtYApwkJoITGGb68tcnnJzsxmpuULD9vqbUTHlYIbl/j1ACTqemq4qKFw5yaAII5IM6usnoXSXEsBBSDkYDC8JiHBMMc4DVLKMD4HJ5O54Dg/Oxvc88sgK@htEyn1JPF1fwCn/5pmmLYSmR8zkJfEkTG6eQDlR@m6j4ZZR6N91AQju4ky/wD@vmo1Pw)