# Generate triangular signal

Tags: code-golf, math, number

### Task:

Given sample index, x, calculate sample value f(x) of triangular wave, with period of 4 samples and amplitude 1. Offset can be negative and sample value could be either {0, 1, -1}.

### Test cases:

```
   -5 -> -1
   -4 -> 0
   -3 -> 1
   -2 -> 0
   -1 -> -1
    0 -> 0
    1 -> 1
    2 -> 0
    3 -> -1
    4 -> 0
    5 -> 1
```

Personally I know two approaches in C - the first is using lookup table, the second is using conditional instructions. For brownie points, could you impress me with a pure "math" approach? (I mean a pure functional approach, e.g. not using conditional instructions or using memory for LUT.) But this is not an restriction. If you can't, or your language does not support it - just post any solution

Comment: What do you mean by "offset can be negative"? Also this is basically just a trigonometric function, so I'd be surprised if it isn't a dupe of something.

Comment: @JungHwanMin This has much more relaxed rules, so it's not really a dupe (though it asks for the same thing).

Comment: @Mego alright. Retracting my vote.

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5522/60043

Comment: Can the wave be out of phase relative to the example?

Comment: How-to Guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073606/is-there-a-one-line-function-that-generates-a-triangle-wave

Answer (score 12):

## Mathematica, 8 bytes

```
Im[I^#]&
```

#### Explanation

```
Im[I^#]&
   I^#    (* Raise the imaginary unit to the input power *)
Im[   ]   (* Take the imaginary part *)
```

Comment: Ohh, beautiful approach. How did I not see this? :D

Comment: cant see algo how to generate imaginary unit in C.. =( im assembler man ^^ using builtins in exotic languages is not in my favor ) however is an answer..

Answer (score 7):

## TI-Basic, <s>7</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
sin(90Ans
```

(Degree mode)
-1 byte from @immibis from my old answer.

---

Old answer

```
imag(i^Ans
```

Pure-math approach on a calculator. :)

Just for fun, here's another pure-math (ish) solution for 9 bytes (In radian mode), or 8 bytes (Degree mode)

```
2/πsin-1sin(πAns/2 # Radians
90-1sin-1sin(90Ans # Degrees
```

Comment: yeah, but you just forget an imag() implementation.. but usin others code is fine, though.. good answer :)

Comment: @xakepp35 I don't understand. `imag()` is a valid function on TI-BASIC.

Comment: What's wrong with `sin(90Ans`? Why do you need the extra `90-1sin-1`?

Comment: @immibis The 90^-1sin^-1 makes it a triangle wave for all values, but sin(90Ans works for what the question asks.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda n:n%2-n%4/3*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5WnaqSbp2qib6xl9L@gKDOvRCE3sUAjTUehKDEvPVVD10LHUlPzPwA)

I'm running a brute-force search for shorter arithmetic or bitwise expressions, I'll see if anything turns up. This one I hand-found.

Comment: Brute force expression search? Nice!

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes

```julia
!n=(2-n&3)%2
```

I like this approach because it's unlikely to be the shortest in any other language.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#@6@YZ6thpJunZqypavQ/Lb9IIU8hM09BQ9fUylSTi9OhoCgzryRNQ0nVKEVB104BSMXkKeko5OkoKOZpcqXmpfwHAA)

#### How it works

Julia's operator precedence is a bit unusual: unlike most other languages, bitwise operators have the same precedence as their arithmetic counterparts, so `&` (bitwise multiplication) has the same precedence as `*`.

First, `n&3` takes the input modulo **4**, with positive sign.

The result – **0**, **1**, **2**, or **3** – is then subtracted from **2**, yielding **2**, **1**, **0**, or **-1**.

Finally, we take the signed remainder of the division by **2**, returning **0**, **1**, **0**, or **-1**.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ı*Ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39ko9aRrv@6pkWmh7Ye3XO4/VHTGvf/AA)

#### How it works

```
ı*Ċ  Main link. Argument: n

ı*   Elevate i, the imaginary unit, to the n-th power.
  Ċ  Take the imaginary part of the result.
```

Answer (score 4):

## dc, 13

Not sure if you count the modulo `%` operator as "pure math":

```
?1+d*v4%1-2%p
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S8svUshUyMxTqNY11dMzrbVWSMnnUgCC1OSMfAWV6kx9fV39@FqFGoWUZAXdVPX/9obaKVplJqqGukaqBf/VuVLy81L/AwA).  Note that `dc` uses `_` instead of `-` to indicate negative numbers.

#### Explanation

```
?              # read input
 1+            # add 1
   d*v         # duplicate, multiply, square root (poor-mans abs())
      4%       # mod 4
        1-     # subtract 1
          2%   # mod 2
            p  # print
```

Note that `dc`'s `%` mod operator is the standard "CPU" version that maps negative values to negative values.

Comment: Can you just do `abs((x+1)%4)-1` instead?

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 136 bytes

```
>,>++++<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>>>>-[>+<-----]>--[-<+>>>+>>>+>>>+<<<<<<<<]<->>>>>>->--[>+<++++++]>++<<<<<<<<<<[[->>>+<<<]>>>-]>[.[-]]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#PYzRCQAxDEIH6tmf@xUXkew/RmtK6YMkYNSlTyPQgnqXzCEUaVauApwXmigwYpDe8FKEDmhT9HGo9PNh42a6OX2eRpXmWv8G)

There's probably a more trivial answer, but this essentially uses a table of values. Although brainfuck takes input as ASCII characters with positive values from 0 to 127, it still works as if it were able to accept negative values (to test, replace the `,` with `n` amount of `-` characters).

## How it works

```
>,                                   take input (X)
>++++<                               take second input for modulo (4)
[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]             calculate X mod 4
>>>>-[>+<-----]>--                   create initial '1' character
[-<+>>>+>>>+>>>+<<<<<<<<]            duplicate '1' four times as 1,1,1,1
<->>>>>>->--[>+<++++++]>++<<<<<<<<<< change 1,1,1,1 to 0,1,0,-1 
[[->>>+<<<]>>>-]>[.[-]]>.            move to the right X%4 * 3 times, then print the following two characters ( 0, 1, 0,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```
lambda x:(1j**x).imag
```

-2 bytes thanks to ValueInk for realizing that the mathematical method is actually longer than the trivial approach :P
-3 bytes thanks to Dennis for pointing out that I don't need the `int(...)`, thus making this shorter :)

Comment: `lambda x:[0,1,0,-1][x%4]` is actually shorter than your int-coerced answer lol

Comment: @ValueInk Oh...um this is embarrasing lol

Comment: Why would you use `int()` in the first place though?

Comment: @Dennis Because `.imag` gives a floating-point value and I'm not sure if that's allowed by the specs. It doesn't matter now :)

Comment: If floats aren't allowed, JavaScript will not be able to compete.

Comment: @Dennis Oh. Okay. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 18 bytes

```
#~JacobiSymbol~46&
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work: inputs 9 and 11 both give 1 as output, for example. The period of this function is 184, not 4.

Comment: However, `JacobiSymbol[-4,#]&` does work, and just costs one more byte. Nice idea!

Comment: again cant see an algrithm( just builtines written by others and couple of short code.. ah, all as usual. fine answer though

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda n:n%2*(2-n%4)
```

An unnamed function which returns the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5WnaqSlYaSbp2qi@T8tv0ihJLW4RCEzT6EoMS89VUPXUkfB0EDTiouzoCgzr0QDJKujoK5rp66jkAbmaWr@BwA)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 12 bytes

```
n->imag(I^n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#S1OwVfifp2uXmZuYruEZl6f5Py2/SCMPKKprqqMARAVFmXklGnk6CkoKunYKSjoKaRp5mpqa/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 20 bytes

```
<?=2<=>($argn&3?:2);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 19 bytes

Port of Dennis's Julia solution, just because he said it wouldn't be shortest in any other language. (Someone might still prove me wrong that it's shortest in Haskell.)

```hs
f n=rem(2-n`mod`4)2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#Hcg7DoQgFAXQrdxiCi0uAcRf4V4kA2YseExQ4/Ix8ZQn@V2WXc5Y/Pf8XHLnEg6V/L85fvlWmyrRh1a9XTfIUmJqLGVNOayutbXSaHAGJ3AEB7AHHdiBFjTQMLDo4NBjwIgJM4x@AA)

Haskell has two different remainder functions, one (`rem`) works like the Julia one, while the other (`mod`) gives a positive result even when the first argument is negative, and so is suitable for translating `&3`. (Haskell's *actual* `&`, called `.&.`, alas requires an `import Data.Bits`.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, a port of Dennis's Julia solution is optimal for JavaScript too (14 bytes). Shows that even Dennis is fallible!

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 22 bytes

```matlab
@(x)round(sin(x*pi/2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7ON@e@gUaFZlF@al6JRnJmnUaFVkKlvpKn5P01D19TKVPM/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 20 bytes

Simple and clean.

```
->x{[0,1,0,-1][x%4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C99, 27 bytes

Assuming you want the wave to be centered at the origin:

```
f(n){return cpow(1i,n)/1i;}
```

otherwise `f(n){return cpow(1i,n);}` will do. I originally had a `cimag` in there, but apparently trying to return an `int` from a `_Complex int` yields the real part, so I used that. It makes sense, but it'snnothing I would have predicted. Behavior is the same in `gcc` and `clang`

Comment: cpow is undefined xD

Comment: some #includes omitted, does not compile)))))

Comment: but +1 just for C

Comment: @xakepp35 That's actually not the fault of the includes, it's a linker problem. Compile with `-std=c99 -lm` and it should work. It works fine for me with both `gcc` and `clang` without any includes. Well, by fine I mean there are no errors, but a large number of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
4%<Ä<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@2@ianO4xeb/f11DAA)

---

**The output is reversed, but from what I understood this is allowed:**

+1 byte to multiply output by -1 using `(`.

```
   -5 -> 1
   -4 -> 0
   -3 -> -1
   -2 -> 0
   -1 -> 1
    0 -> 0
    1 -> -1
    2 -> 0
    3 -> 1
    4 -> 0
    5 -> -1
```

---

```
4%    # Amplitude of 4...
  <   # Period of 1...
   Ä  # Absolute value...
    < # Period of 1 centered at 0...
```

Comment: *what I understood this is allowed*

Comment: test cases are not passed ;-)

Comment: but +1 nice try

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 7 bytes (possibly 6)

```
ta2%tQ4
```

[Try it](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ta2%25tQ4&input=3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-5%0A-4%0A-3%0A-2%0A-1%0A0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7&debug=0)

If the phase of the wave isn't important, 6 bytes:

```
ta2%Q4
```

[Try it](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ta2%25Q4&input=3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-5%0A-4%0A-3%0A-2%0A-1%0A0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
ta2%tQ4
     Q    # The input
    t     # Subtract 1 to get the phase right (might not be necessary)
   %  4   # Take mod 4
 a2       # Absolute value of the result - 2
t         # Subtract 1 so the result is in [-1,0,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 26 bytes

```
{$0=(sqrt(($0%4)^2)-2)%2}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@1@tYmCrUVxYVKKhoWKgaqIZZ6Spa6SpalRr@P@/rimXrgmXrjGXrhGXriGXAZchlxGXMZcJlykA)

This is an alternate approach using trig functions without the modulus operator.

```
{$0=int(sin($0*atan2(0,-1)/2))}1
```

[Try it online !](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#BcExEoAgDATA/t5BQRxvTAKUPoaSJo10jm@Pu/kWvVfs@qyoRY@5Z3jVkyaXi3yWyQF2sIEOGhQGR0PH@AE)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
n=>n&1&&(++n&2)-1
```

Firstly, check if the input is even or odd and return 0 for all even values. For all odd inputs, increment and bitwise with `0b10` to remove any bits that don't interest us, then return the answer with an offset.

```js
const f = n=>n&1&&(++n&2)-1;

for (let i = -5; i < 6; i++) {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = `f(${i}) => ${f(i)}`;
}
```

Comment: Save a byte by replacing `? :0` with `&&`

Comment: @SteveBennett Thanks, great idea!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 15 bytes

```
n=>n&3&&2-(n&3)
```

Bitwise and 3 is equivalent to modulo 4 except without the weird rule on JavaScript's modulos of negative numbers. I did polynomial regression on the first four points at first but then realized I was being dumb because (1, 1), (2, 0), and (3, -1) is just 2-n.

```js
a=n=>n&1&&2-(n&3);
console.log([a(-5), a(-4), a(-3), a(-2), a(-1), a(0), a(1), a(2), a(3), a(4), a(5)])
```

Comment: very well! +1 for the answer

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 19 bytes

```r
function(n)Im(1i^n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNP0zNXwzAzLk/zf5qGrqmVqeZ/AA)

A port of [JungHwan Min's Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120752/67312).